# Is there any way to grab a slice to the end of an anonymous array in Perl?

Tags: perl

So this has been making me go bonkers for the last half hour. Is there any way for me to grab an array slice to the end of an anonymous array? I've tried:
`(split(' ',$test_line))[1..$#_]`
and I've tried:
`(split(' ',$test_line))[1..-1]`
but aggravatingly, neither of those work. I really don't want to have an extra temp variable instantiated to the intermediate array (which I don't need). And I really don't want to use an ugly and unreadable one liner (found a few of those online). Is there really no straight forward way to do this?

Comment: I suspect the best answer will be the extra temp variable. On your first line, the reason `$#_` doesn't work is that `@_` is not the list from the expression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A list, which is what you have in your example, can not be sliced from the end.  This is mainly because lists are not proper data structures in Perl, but more a construct that the interpreter uses to move data around.  So knowing that you can only slice a list from the begining, your options are to either put it in an array variable and then slice, change your algorithm to return what you want, or the following:

If you are assigning this value to something, you can use `undef` in each slot you dont want:

```
 my (undef, @list) = split ' ' => $test_line;
```

If you post some more code, I can revise.

Alternatively, you can use some tools from functional programming.  The pair of functions `drop` and `take` can be useful to resize a list without additional variables:

```
sub take {
    my $n = shift;
    @_[0..$n-1]
}
sub drop {
    my $n = shift;
    @_[$n..$#_]
}
```

and then your example becomes

```
drop 1, split ' ' => $test_line;
```

`drop 1` is also commonly called `tail`

```
sub tail {drop 1, @_}
```

and of course, since all of these are so short, if you wanted to inline it:

```
sub {shift; @_}->(split ' ' => ...)
```

Comment: My idea is along the lines of:
my %test_hash = (split(' ',$test_line))[1..$#_];

In that particular case, your approach works well, but I was hoping for something a bit more generic, so that when I don't want the first 10 items, I won't be stuck writing out undef 10 times...

Comment: @Eli => sadly that's not a feature of list slices in perl5.  The generic solution is something like `drop` or `take`.  Depending on your content, you might also be able to use grep to remove the items you dont want.

Comment: Nice answer. There *are* one-liner solutions, but they really don’t belong in production code.

Comment: Well, it's not really the answer I wanted, but it seems like the best answer given the constraints. Just another reason for me to not like Perl, I guess.

Comment: @Eli => Keep learning, I find that in most places where Perl's syntax doesn't seem fit the problem well, there is often a different way to approach it that ends up being much cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

When the OP said *slice*, I thought of [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
@allTheWordsExceptTheFirstTwo = splice @{[split' ', $test_line]}, 2;
@allExceptTheFirstAndLastTwo = splice @{[split' ', $test_line]}, 2, -2;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use negative ranges in the array subscript to address an arbitrary number of elements from the end:

```
my $x = join ' ' => 'a' .. 'z';
my @x = (split ' ', $x)[-13 .. -1];
```

However, this requires you to know the total number of elements in the result of `split` to eliminate just the first element.

If this happens in only one place, using a `do` block should work:

```
my $x = join ' ', 'a' .. 'z';
my @x = do { my @y = (split ' ', $x); @y[1 .. $#y] };
```

In your case, I would factor out the whole operation to a subroutine if it is supposed to be used frequently, passing the string rather than the result of the `split` to the subroutine (can be further generalized by allowing the user to pass the split pattern as well:

```
my $x = join ' ', 'a' .. 'g';
my @x = skip_first_n_from_split(3, $x);

print Dump \@x;

sub skip_first_n_from_split {
    my ($n, $x) = @_;
    my @y = split ' ', $x;
    return @y[$n .. $#y];
}
```

Having fun:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $x = join ' ', 1 .. 8;
my @skippers = map make_skipper(' ', $_), 0 .. 7;

print "@$_\n" for map $_->($x), @skippers;

sub make_skipper {
    my ($pattern, $n) = @_;

    return sub {
        my $string = shift;
        my $i = 0;
        return [ grep $i++ >= $n, split $pattern, $string ];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8
6 7 8
7 8
8
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can specify an index for the last element of an arbitrary list expression, but how about:

```
split(' ', (split ' ', $test_line, 2)[1])
```

By the way, there are no anonymous arrays here (or in your original question), only lists.

Comment: Not the prettiest, calling `split` twice.  You could also use `split " " => ($test_line =~ /\s+(.*)/s && $1)`, but I wouldn't advocate that.

Comment: Perhaps not the prettiest, but at least it's short and relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

This just got [answered](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=873993) 'neatly' on Perlmonks by BrowserUK, this is what you'd do:

```
my @slice =  sub{ @_[1..$#_] }->( split ' ', $test_line );
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're open to splitting twice:

```
my @g =  (split ' ', $test_str)[1..split(' ', $test_str)];
```

or more correctly (since split returns the number of  fields found (one more than the last field's index since it is 0-based):

```
my @g =  (split ' ', $test_str)[1..split(' ', $test_str)-1];
```

unfortunately these throw a deprecated warning under 'warnings' pragma, and clobbers the contents of @_ (unless you're using 5.12, then you're good, otherwise go with a temporary variable, inline sub or a loop).